# Inserting one input value from two database column name

Tags: php, mysql

I need help on a topic from you.

I have only one `<input>` for name:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name_" placeholder="Your Name">
```

and here is my post code:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db.php';
include_once 'includes/user.php';
include_once'includes/alphaID.php';
$user = new user();
$set_error='';
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$rname=$_POST['name'];
$name = alphaID(microtime(true) * 10000);

if (strlen($rname)>0)
{


$set=$user->Create_Name($name,$rname,$uid,$uemail);
if($set)
{
$_SESSION['id']=$set;

}
else
{
$set_error="<span class='seterror'>name is already exists.</span>";
}
}
}
?>
```

and insert code is here:

```
<?php 
  class user 
  {  
      public function Create_Name($name,$rname,$uid,$uemail) 
  {
        $name= mysql_real_escape_string($name);
        $rname= mysql_real_escape_string($name);
        $rname= mysql_real_escape_string($rname);
        $qu= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE rname='$rname'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($qu)==0)
        {
           $id = "{$uid}";
           $cekme = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '$id'");
           $goster = mysql_fetch_array($cekme);
           extract($goster);
           $email = "{$email}"; 
           var_dump($name);
           var_dump($rname);
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(name,rname,uid,uemail)VALUES('$name','$rname','$uid','$email')");
            return $id=mysql_insert_id() ;    
     }
     else
     {
     return false;
     }
  }   
}

?>
```

Now what i am trying to do. You can see here `$name` this `$name` is posted with alphaID.php .
The alphaID() value based on microtime() and it always changes. 
Like

name= Lorem impsum dolar

to

name= ebO80dHE

Now at the same time i want to post the real name (Lorem impsum dolar) from  `rname` .

My code posting alphaID `name` but `rname` is not posting.

name = `string(8) "ebO80dHE"`
rname = `string(0) ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $name= mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $rname= mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $rname= mysql_real_escape_string($rname);
```

Remove second line:

```
    $name= mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $rname= mysql_real_escape_string($rname);
```

Also, try printing the name here:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$rname=$_POST['name'];
var_dump($rname);

$name = alphaID(microtime(true) * 10000);
```

`if (strlen($rname)>0)` — if that is true, I don't see how `rname` can be empty in code you've posted.

Try adding more var_dumps of `rname` in `public function Create_Name`: in the beginning and right after `$rname= mysql_real_escape_string` - anywhere the `$rname` changes. This should give the exact place where it becomes empty.

Comment: Print the name before any processing, might as well be a problem with form input.

Comment: after  `$rname=$_POST['rname']; var_dump($rname);` is showing my the rname where is the problem here ?

Comment: `if (strlen($rname)>0)` - if that is true, I don't see how `rname` can be empty in code you've posted. Try adding more var_dumps of `rname` in `public function Create_Name`: in the beginning and right after `$rname= mysql_real_escape_string` - anywhere the `$rname` changes. This should give the exact place where it becomes empty.